# Install cudf without conda

Tags: python, pip, gpu, conda, cudf

On google colab I installed conda and then cudf through conda. However now i need to reinstall all packages like sklearn etc which I am using in my code. Is there some way to install cudf without conda ? pip no more works with cudf. Also if there is some other similar gpu dataframe which can be installed using pip, it will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

No, cudf is not available as a pip package.

You don't say why you need cudf, but I would try pandas, dask or vaex, surely one of those will do what you need.

Comment: I need cudf because I want to utilize GPU of google colab. cudf work much faster than pandas.

Answer (score 0):

from [rapids page](https://rapids.ai/pip.html#install) you can use the cmds below, but be aware that this is still experimental:

```
pip install cudf-cu11 dask-cudf-cu11 --extra-index-url=https://pypi.nvidia.com
pip install cuml-cu11 --extra-index-url=https://pypi.nvidia.com
pip install cugraph-cu11 --extra-index-url=https://pypi.nvidia.com
```

EDIT: thanks to [sparta0000](https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/issues/12762)

```
!pip install cudf-cu11==22.12 rmm-cu11==22.12 dask-cudf-cu11==22.12 --extra-index-url=https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com/
```